# return multiple values inside function method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my query counting rows in `tblapplication`

```
public function countallrecord() {
    $query = $this->db->get('tblapplication');

    return $query->num_rows();  
}
```

and this is the function to get all the data

```
public function getdata() {
    $query = $this->db->get('tblapplication');

    return $query->result();
}
```

Is there any way I can make this code on one function

I'm trying to pass it here:

```
public function Countandviewallrecord() {
    // returns both rows and count
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return it as an array. Include the results and count in their respective indices:

```
public function get_records()
{
    $result = $this->db->get('tblapplication');
    $data['results'] = $result->result();
    $data['count'] = $result->num_rows;

    return $data;
}
```

When accessing the model method in your controller, the usual:

```
$data = $this->model_name->get_records();

echo $data['count']; // whatever number this is
if($data['count'] > 0) {
    foreach($data['results'] as $row) {
        echo $row->column_name; // etc blah blah ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what im looking!

Answer (score 0):

this Countandviewallrecord will display data as well count total records

```
public function Countandviewallrecord(){

$TotalRecords= $this->countallrecord();
$totalData= $this->getdata();

    }
```